# When it's ok to not follow the plural model convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know when it's ok to not follow the plural model convention.

I have two models:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :site
  has_many :metrics, class_name: 'Metrics', dependent: :delete_all
end

class Metrics < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I've created other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58560574/validation-failed-metrics-must-exist?noredirect=1#comment103444348_58560574) that other users of SO said that it's wrong to have pluralized model names, but in the case of `Metrics` it would be super weird to call it `Metric`. I would like to understand the convention around that – is it ok to sacrifice the convention over readability?

Comment: Rails convention over configuration principle expects singular model names and many of the libraries built that live alongside them do too. I'd take a look at some of the larger open-source Rails apps and see if you can find when they've bent the rules, and how that context would apply to your app. Upon a quick glance Discourse, I didn't see any AR models that are pluralized.

Comment: Check the guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions, you can skip the convention, but rails assumes a lot of thing that you have to be careful (like it expect some things to be singular or plural and it automatically pluralizes or singularizes strings when it need to by default), you can hardcode what rails tries to infere though, but it requires more code

Comment: Why would it "be super weird to call it Metric"? Metric is the singular form of metrics Your `Post` has many metrics and each `Metric` belongs to a `Post`

Comment: I agree here, metric is a completely normal countable noun. If anything using the plural metrics for a model name is super weird and does nothing for readability.

Answer (score 2):

No. You ALWAYS use singular model name, plural controller name, and plural table names. You should never break this convention.

tl;dr it's never ok (However, this is just personal opinion and how I was taught. I believe that's also how it is in Rails style guide)

https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rails-style-guide

```
model Metric
controller MetricsController
table metrics
routes: either resources metrics or resource metric
```

Notice how even with a singular resource, the controller is still plural?

https://gist.github.com/iangreenleaf/b206d09c587e8fc6399e

Think about what would happen if you had like 30 models that were singular, then one that was plural and how confusing that would be.

Answer (score 2):

What `TedTran2019` said.

Not knowing anything about your domain, I would be tempted to have a `PostMetric` model something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: post_metrics
#
#  id                     :bigint           not null, primary key
#  post_id                :integer          not null
#  metric_id              :ingeger          not null
#  value                  :string           not null
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#
class PostMetric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :metric
end
```

...and a `Post` model something like:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :site
  has_many :post_metrics, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :metrics, through: :post_metrics

  Metric.all.pluck(:name).each do |metric_name|
    define_method("#{metric_name}_metric") do 
      metrics.where(name: metric_name)
    end
    define_method("post_#{metric_name}_metric") do 
      post_metrics.where(metric: send("#{metric_name}_metric"))
    end
  end

end
```

...and a `Metric` model something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: metrics
#
#  id                     :bigint           not null, primary key
#  name                   :string          not null
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#
class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_metrics
  has_many :posts, through: :post_metrics
end
```

Naturally, you would need to `seed` (or otherwise create) each of your `Metric` records.

That way, your `Post` responds to `metrics` and `Metric` is a non-super-weird model name.

Also, you'll be able to do something like `@post.view_metric` and `@post.post_view_metric` (to retrieve the join model, in case that's helpful).

When you delete a `Post` record, it'll destroy all the associated `PostMetric` join models, but leave your `Metric` models intact.

Answer (score 0):

Check the guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions, you can skip the convention, but rails assumes a lot of thing that you have to be careful (like it expect some things to be singular or plural and it automatically pluralizes or singularizes strings when it need to by default), you can hardcode what rails tries to infere though, but it requires more code.

Note that you ask about "readability". When you get used to rails' conventions "Metric" is clearer to read than "Metrics", since, in the rails' context, it gives you a lot more information about the name of other things too.

Usually, I break rails conventions on things like database keys or tables if the database came from another system, for new things I would try to always stick to rails conventions unless there's a real solid argument with proven benefit on not using it.

EDIT: there's also some irregular nouns that you should use carefully too, like, if you have a news site, "news" is both plural and singular, so you may want to change the model name to NewsArticle so you can have "news article" and "news articles" and the table "news_articles" for example.

Comment: News is actually more specially an uncountable noun and not just irregular.